# Restangular error handling issue

Tags: error-handling, restangular

I'm having an issue with restangular. This code :

```
Restangular.one("undefined_ressource").get().then(
    function(res){
        console.log("success", res.code);
    },
    function (res) {
        console.log("fail", res.code);
   }
);
```

Tries to get the url `http://api.local.com/undefined_ressource` which does not exits. My server returns a 404, as expected, but the fail log is never fired. Intead it goes in the success callback and logs `"success 404"` to the console.

```
Angular version 1.2.15
Restangular version 1.3.1
```

Any help would be welcomed! Thanks

Comment: do you have interceptor in your config?

Comment: Yes I do. I tried without interceptor but it does not change anything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Adapted from your code example**

```
Restangular.one("undefined_ressource").get().then(
    function(myObject){
        console.log("success obtained myObject");
    },
    function (res) {
        console.log("fail", res.status);
   }
);
```

- If Restangular call is successful:

*then* first function should be invoked 
and its argument should be **myObject**.
Unless your **myObject** has a specific **code or status** field, there won't be any added by Restangular.

- If Restangular call fails:

*then* second function should be invoked and its argument be a **response** object with status, header, data, config fields. 
There shouldn't be any **code** field available as shown in your example.

**In case of an HTTP 404 Not Found exception**, in my navigator javascript console I do obtain:
    "fail" 404

**With error interceptor**

```
myAngularApp.run(['Restangular', '$window', function(Restangular, $window){
    Restangular.setErrorInterceptor(
        function(response) {
            if (response.status == 401) {
                console.log("Login required... ");
                $window.location.href='/login';
            } else if (response.status == 404) {
                console.log("Resource not available...");
            } else {
                console.log("Response received with HTTP error code: " + response.status );
            }
            return false; // stop the promise chain
        }
    );
}]);
```

If an error interceptor is set up on your angular application **myAngularApp** as in the above example, the failure should no more reach your custom call *then* second function but be processed by the errorInterceptor set up function.

**In case of an HTTP 404 Not Found exception**, in my navigator javascript console I do obtain: Resource not available...

*Tested with:*

```
Angular version 1.2.14
Restangular version 1.3.1
```

Comment: You are missing a }]); at the end to close the run function !

Comment: @etiennenoel now fixed! In addition I tried to make the formatting a bit easier to read. Thanks!

Comment: Curious to know if you remove your responseInterceptor and try the *then* call using both the success and error handlers if you experience the same thing.  

In my case I was getting a 404 status but the success callback was triggered.  I then removed my responseInterceptor and the error callback was triggered.  Something about adding a responseInterceptor messes w/ Restangular **and** $http's ability to process responses normall.  I added $http to this as well as it experiences the same issue.

Comment: @jusopi you are talking about `ResponseInterceptor` which also exists in Restangular but here I only described `ErrorInterceptor` behaviour, make sure not to mix them up. Useful official documentation: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#seterrorinterceptor and https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setresponseinterceptor

Comment: @patrick-refondiniI got a little hung up in scrolling back and forth that I commented on the wrong section.  I have found the ErrorInterceptor not to be very useful aside from logging in that if you return false, it never makes it back to the promise chain (be it a then or catch).  Anything else proceeds through the promise chain which you might as well handle in a ResponseInterceptor.

Comment: @jusopi `ErrorInterceptor` is only useful to centralise error management, for instance when you find yourself always coding the same behaviour to handle errors. This behaviour can be anything you need like displaying popup with a message to the end-user or redirecting to a login page,... not just logging. Otherwise just stick to pattern: `.then(function(myObject){ //success }, function (res) { // failure });`

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same symptoms as expressed in the original post above: HTTP Status OK is fine, however HTTP errors throw success.

The highest rated example didn't help at all because I didn't have an setErrorInterceptor (at the time), addResponseInterceptor doesn't trigger or errors, and finally the setErrorInterceptor I added seemed to be triggering **after** the promise was resolving as OK.

It turned out the problem was an error in the promise chain of my code. Make sure if you have a promise chain that each promise being generated returns the promise, else what is happening will be an earlier promise is resolving successfully and that is being returned, instead of the chained part that is failing.

Just a tip for others in case you run into this.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work only by adding an interceptor to the `$httpProvider` in my config in addition to using my config for the `RestangularProvider`

src - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

```
// HttpConfig.js
function( $httpProvider )
{
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push( function( $q, $rootScope )
    {
        return {
            'request': function( config )
            {
                return config;
            },

            'requestError': function( rejection )
            {
                return rejection;
            },

            'response':     function( response )
            {
                return response;
            },

            //THIS is what makes it work for me
            'responseError': function( rejection )
            {
                return $q.reject( rejection );
            }
        };
    } );
}
```